# Installing XGBoost on EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, installation, anaconda, xgboost

I have tried for 3 days and followed the following directions to get XGBoost on my EC2 instance:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xgboost/
- http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

I also tried:
sudo apt-get install build-essential
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4
cd python-package
sudo python setup.py install

then it errored out at sudo: python: command not found.

I also have little to no knowledge of Linux, e.g. export, environment, sudo, very little knowledge on what they do.

I used Anaconda and the conda command to install all my other programs, such as numpy and sklearn. Now I want to add XGBoost to my EC2 instance. I followed all those directions to the dot and I ALWAYS run into issues. Whether that be import xgboost fails in Python because it can't find GLIXXX in libstdc++.so.6 or something like that, or I tried to to do sudo python setup.py install and it says `sudo: python: command not found` (for that matter, `sudo conda` also doesn't work. I'm sure it's some Path issue, but again I have no knowledge on how path works in Linux...I tried to learn it but I just can't.)

I guess all directions I found online doesn't take into account that I'm using Anaconda.

Any tips/help will be truly appreciated, and I will be sure to mark it as answer so NO ONE ELSE in my situation has to waste 3 days following instructions that do not work.

I managed to install xgboost and I can see xgboost available in my jupyter notebook. But when I tried to run the `import xgboost` command in my notebook, I get the following error:

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import xgboost
>
> /home/ubuntu/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/**init**.py in ()
>         9 import os
>        10 
>   ---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, Booster
>        12 from .training import train, cv
>        13 from . import rabit                   # noqa
>
> /home/ubuntu/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/core.py in ()
>       110 
>       111 # load the XGBoost library globally
>   --> 112 _LIB = _load_lib()
>       113 
>       114
>
> /home/ubuntu/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/core.py in _load_lib()
>       104     if len(lib_path) == 0:
>       105         return None
>   --> 106     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
>       107     lib.XGBGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
>       108     return lib
>
> /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.pyc in
>   LoadLibrary(self, name)
>       438 
>       439     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
>   --> 440         return self._dlltype(name)
>       441 
>       442 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)
>
> /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.pyc in
>   **init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
>       360 
>       361         if handle is None:
>   --> 362             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>       363         else:
>       364             self._handle = handle
>
> OSError:
>   /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6:
>   version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by
>   /home/ubuntu/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so)